# Populating a vector with a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to fill a vector `pred_pos` with the result `pred` on each iteration of the for loop. However, my `pred_pos` vector is never filled. The `my_vec` object is a list of large character vectors which I don't believe needs to be reproduced for this problem as it is most likely a fundamental indexing error. I just need to know how to populate a vector from this for loop. I can't seem to work out a solution.

```
pred_pos <- vector("numeric" , 2)


for(i in my_vec) { 
        for(r in pred_pos) {
        inserts <- sapply(i, function(n) { n <- cond_probs_neg[n] } ) 
        pred <- sum(unlist(inserts) , na.rm = T) * apriori_neg
        pred_pos[r] <- pred
        } 
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the rest of your code works, there is no need to explicitly state:

`pred_pos <- vector("numeric" , 2)`

That creates a numeric vector of length two. You ought to be able to write:

`pred_pos <- vector()`

Now when you wish to append to the vector you can simply use:

`vector[length(vector)+1] <- someData`

I believe your code should work if it is adjusted:

```
pred_pos <- vector()

for(i in my_vec) { 
        inserts <- sapply(i, function(n) { n <- cond_probs_neg[n] } ) 
        pred <- sum(unlist(inserts) , na.rm = T) * apriori_neg
        pred_pos[length(pred_pos)+1] <- pred
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. It actually works perfectly if I omit the for(r in pred_pos) loop entirely and just use the first for loop.

Comment: Yes. Nice use of the index counter too to populate the vector. Thanks again.